# Existe alguna forma de mostrar el contenido del TableView sólo cuando el SearchController está activo?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Tengo un SearchController dentro de un TableView, pero esto lo tengo en medio de la pantalla, por lo tanto, cuando filtro los datos a través del SearchController, este se desplaza hacia arriba y el TableView queda inmóvil en la mitad de la pantalla... Lo que estoy buscando es cómo hacer para que cuando active el SearchController, este se desplace con todo el TableView hacia arriba de la pantalla y muestre el TableView en toda la pantalla sobre los otros objetos mientras filtro los datos con el SearchController, una vez que cancele la búsqueda o filtro que retornen a su posición normal. Algo así...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene idea de cómo se puede realizar esto?, espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que tu tableview ocupa la mitad de la pantalla y quieres que cuando empieces a buscar la ocupe entera? Es que no sé si te he entendido bien

Comment: Exacto, está en la mitad de abajo mi tableview, la idea es que cuando empiece a buscar se deslice hacia arriba con el searchcontroller y ocupe la pantalla completa... Es posible?

Comment: Claro. Los constraints de la tableview los tienes puestos por storyboard o por código?

Comment: Están por storyboard Manuel

Answer (score 0):

No se si resolviste este asunto ya pero te recomiendo que ponga en storyboard un curtains mas al tableview con el fondo del viewController o sea el bottom o el safe area bottom y tengas una referencia a el, así como una referencia al bottom del tableView a la siguiente vista que tenga debajo y segundo actives el searchController  actives un constrain y desactives el otro y al del view bottom. al activar los delegados de `UISearchControllerDelegate` en la funcion

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
   self.tableViewBottonConstraint.isActive = false
   self.bottonContrains.costan = 0
   self.bottonContrains.isActive = true
  //resto del codigo de la busqueda
}
```

donde TableViewBottonConstrain seria el contrain entre el tableview y la vista siguiente y bottonConstrain un constraint entre el tableView y el fondo de la vista del viewController.
luego en `func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        //haces el proceso contrario
       self.tableViewBottonConstraint.isActive = true
       self.bottonContrains.isActive = false 
      //resto del codigo para limpiar el serachController
    }`

espero te sirva